# Wire installation code - burying optical cables

Tags: ethernet, network

It has been brought to my attention that a local construction company will be installing fiber and is offerring to install fiber straight to the home at no cost.

Previous experience shows that these companies do a very poor job at installing cables, a gentle sneeze can knock out an entire block's network conenctivity.

Is there any code that I can ensure the installers adhere to? I am in Ontario. I can find building code for installing electrical lines, but non-mains lines don't seem to be covered in that section.

Comment: And where does the other end go? Typical in my area (Maryland) is that any fiber install is provided by an internet service provider.

Comment: that sounds somewhat fishy ... why would a construction company do this? ... usually it is something like telco that pulls fibre cables through existing copper line conduits

Comment: Company has been contracted by Bell (big telco).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there code that applies to fiber optics?

NFPA 70, the "National Electric Code" (at least in USA) does have some words to say about optical cables. I had thought that Canada used it too but I'm not certain.

In the 2017 edition, Article 840 Premises-Powered Broadband Communications Systems begins by defining its scope as follows:

> 840.1 Scope. This article covers premises-powered broadband communications systems.
>
> Informational Note No. 1: A typical basic system configuration consists of an **optical fiber**, twisted pair, or coaxial cable **to the premises supplying a broadband signal** to a network terminal that converts the broadband signal into component electrical signals, such as traditional telephone, video, **high-speed Internet**, and interactive services.

In case anybody is not convinced of its applicability to utilities, wording of Part II Cables Outside and Entering Buildings makes it pretty clear they're talking about utility-owned cables:

> 840.44(A) On Poles and In-Span. Where outside plant optical fiber cables and electric light or power conductors are supported by the same pole ...

> 840.44(A)(2) Attachment to Cross-Arms. Attachment of outside plant optical fiber cables to a cross-arm that carries electric light or power conductors shall not be permitted.

Section 840.47 Underground Wires and Cables Entering Buildings has some rules about separation of conductive optical fiber cables when sharing a raceway or direct-buried near power circuits. It also specifies that direct-buried cable, conduit shall have minimum cover of 150 mm/6".

Optical cables can contain non-current-carrying metallic members (specifically, armor to protect the cable and/or a tracer wire used in locating buried cable). Outdoors, at least, that conductor integrated into the cable is what draws NFPA's interest.

The code also concerns itself with fiber optics inside buildings, but I'm not going to recite any of that here because it's not the subject of the question.

#### Does the code apply to an ISP/utility?

So - the code *covers* fiber optic utility activities, but is there any force of law that *obligates a utility to follow the code*? Yes, there can be. I'm personally involved in a small fiber-to-the-home ISP and an agreement with a municipality where we operate does stipulate compliance with NEC.

#### Can you ensure anything?

You probably don't have any standing to oversee or ensure that the installers do anything. You're not the "Authority Having Jurisdiction" and you're not the one paying the bills and calling the shots for the workers. There's probably little opportunity for you to make any demands about their quality or practices.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the NEC applies to fiber-optic ISP utilities? It doesn’t even apply to electric utilities.

Comment: @nobody Yes, in a city where I'm involved in operating a fiber-optic ISP utility, NEC does apply to the operation.

Comment: This correctly answers the question - thank you! The wording of the notice implies I have jurisdiction to decide whether or not they continue the install to my property. If all I get is blank stares when I ask "Are you NEC compliant", then I guess the answer will be no thanks.

Comment: CEC and CSA standards are what applies in Canada. They are usually similar, but I'd hardly expect a Canadian company in Canada to be instaliing to NEC (USA) standards.

Answer (score 2):

While you quite probably won't find references to "fiber optic cable" the more generic "communications system" includes that, and appears to be addressed in **CAN/CSA C22.3 No. 7 Underground Installations** to the extent that I can determine without purchasing the standard. That appears to be incorporated into the Canadian Electrical Code by reference.

All-dielectric cable gets a pass on certain things since it's non-conductive, but standards DO apply.

Comments are correct that YOU can't really do squat about forcing compliance since you are not hiring the company to do the install. On the other hand, you definitely want to get in when it's "run to your house for free" unless there's specific requirement for some term of service that is unappealing. I'm the last house on my road with Cable TV, (well, actually I only get internet from them) because I was evidently the last house that said yes, I wanted it, when they were "running it to the end of the road" They ran the carrier cable to the end of the road, but not the coax, and at this point getting them to extend the coax is *very not free.* My coax sat there for years before I had them turn it on, without costing me anything.

Answer (score -3):

There is no code for optical cables. They transmit light, which is harmless. The only code issue would be concealing it behind drywall. I don't know what the type of cable you would need for that. The problem is smoke contribution during a fire.

If you want to bury it or run it outside exposed to sunlight, make sure your cable is rated for direct burial and UV exposure.

Comment: There is code for optical cables, and the light transmitted cannot be assumed to be harmless. Hazard warnings are routinely plastered all over fiber optic telecom equipment and patch panels. The light can be quite powerful, and in most cases is at wavelengths not visible to the human eye (but they can still cause damage).

Comment: Really? That sounds like argument for sake if argument bro.

Comment: I want the construction company to install it in a way that mowing my lawn or stepping on a particular area of my lawn does not destroy a cable (both things that have previously happened to me)

Comment: In which case you call the service provider to repair it...